# What is causing the bug in "mix-blend-mode mode" with .mp4 on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, firefox, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to use  mix-blend-mode with a mp4 in the background. The idea is to have div with some text and have the video play in the background for an effect on the letters. This works perfectly with every browser besides Firefox.

On Firefox the video plays in the background but mix-blend-mode doesn't seem to have any effect. The text is just black. Here is the weird part: If I open the inspector the animations start to work but for one time only. I thought it might be a permission issue and allowed autoplay but that didn't solve the problem. I haven't been able to find what causes the bug. Any suggestions or hacks would be most welcome :)

Ive made the bit available on gitHub and live at netlify. Here is the repo on [github](https://github.com/emelieedman/firefox-bug) and [live version](https://firefox-bug.netlify.app) on netlify. If you want to see it clearly.

the HTLM bit looks like this:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="scroll-container">
            <video className="background-video" autoPlay="autoplay" muted loop>
                <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="header">
                    THE CREATIVE
                    <br />
                    WEB AGENCY
                    <br />
                    DESIGN/CODE
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and here is the css:

```css
.text {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: black;
    z-index: 1;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you make us a snippet so we can try this out - particularly the bit about it (partly) working with inspector. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ive made the bit available on gitHub and live at netlify. Here is the repo on github: https://github.com/emelieedman/firefox-bug and live at https://firefox-bug.netlify.app/

Comment: I'm stumped as tried it on FF with all permissions re autoplay etc and just saw black. Couple of thoughts though - have you tried a smaller (bytewise) video as FF maybe is trying to load chunks? And is the auto sizing (widthwise) working on FF because it looks as though the video smoke bit is off to the right. And have you tried running with nothing but the video displayed - does it definitely play? Sorry not to be more helpful.

Comment: yes thats the funny part if you remove the writing the video plays fine... Ill try your other suggestions see if they help :) thank you

Comment: This hit us too. A user reported the issue but I wasn't able to see the problem until I upgraded my Firefox to v88.

Comment: For some reason adding opacity: 0.98 to the video or an ancestor fixes the problem for me.  0.99 won't work though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I can confirm. It worked as intended in Firefox v87.0 and doesn't work in v88.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [bug 1708444](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1708444) and it should be fixed in v. 89.

Comment: just upgraded my firefox. The bug is fixed :D. hallelujah